# Extracting each instance of a group of tags from an xml file and Parsing as a Column

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I have a data set of evernote data (reference previous questions) the list of tags for each note include (title, created, updated, latitude, longitude, mime, timestamp, file-name). I was able to extract these specific elements as a list and there in lies my problem. 
First I declared each tag as a variable using BeautifulSoup

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(open('myNotes.xml','r'))
title = soup.findAll('title')
created = soup.findAll('created')
updated = soup.findAll('updated')
latitude = soup.findAll('latitude')
longitude = soup.findAll('longitude')
mime = soup.findAll('mime')
timestamp = soup.findAll('timestamp')

all = title + created
print all
```

It prints all the results for each individual tag, then moves on to the next. 
Each note element has all of these tags and I would like it to print each row with all of the preceding tags to maintain the integrity of each note listing.

The idea is for it to show up as: 
-Note:(title, created, updated, latitude, longitude, mime, timestamp, file-name)
-Note:(title, created, updated, latitude, longitude, mime, timestamp, file-name)
-Note:(title, created, updated, latitude, longitude, mime, timestamp, file-name)

rather than:
title title title, created created created, latitude latitude latitude, logitude... you get the picture.
When I `print all`

Here's some of my data - 
`<title>
 UX observation
</title>
,
<title>
 UI framework.
</title>
,
<title>
 Attachment:AudioNote-2011-04-04_092442.amr
</title>
,
<title>
 Snapshot
</title>
,
<title>
 Tableau
</title>
,
<title>
 Jquery plugins.
</title>
,
<title>
 Sacred geometry
</title>
,
<title>
 Audio from 625 Hyde St in San Francisco
</title>
,
<title>
 Potential coding resources
</title>`

It prints all of the  tags first and then moves to the  tag and does the same.
The problem is I loose the rows containing each tag. I'd like for each title be displayed with its corresponding , ,  in a single row (as a single note), and then move on to the next set.
Hope that clarifies.

Comment: Can you post some of your data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of just searching for all matches of several tags, you should look for the main tag you want, then parse the children of it. Consider the following evernote XML export:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE en-export SYSTEM "http://xml.evernote.com/pub/evernote-export3.dtd">
<en-export export-date="20131123T093001Z" application="Evernote" version="Evernote Mac 5.4.3 (402231)">
<note><title>Untitled Note</title><content><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE en-note SYSTEM "http://xml.evernote.com/pub/enml2.dtd">
<en-note style="word-wrap: break-word; -webkit-nbsp-mode: space; -webkit-line-break: after-white-space;">
Test Entry
<div>Another Entry</div>
<div>Yet Another Entry<span style="-evernote-last-insertion-point:true;"/></div>
</en-note>
]]></content><created>20131123T092930Z</created><updated>20131123T092953Z</updated><note-attributes><author>Steven Parker</author><reminder-order>0</reminder-order></note-attributes></note>
</en-export>
```

You can parse the note like this:

```
from lxml import etree
with open(u'/path/to/my_evernote_file.enex', 'rb') as src_file:
    my_xml_file = src_file.read()
root = etree.fromstring(my_xml_file)
```

Now that you have access to the root node, you can find your `note` tag elements, which is what you're after:

```
for note in root.xpath('//note'):  # Locate all tags under the root named 'note'. There's one.
    my_values = dict(
        title = note.xpath('title'),
        created = note.xpath('created'),
        updated = note.xpath('updated'),
        latitude = note.xpath('latitude'),
        longitude = note.xpath('longitude'),
        mime = note.xpath('mime'),
        timestamp = note.xpath('timestamp'),
    )
```

`my_values` now looks like this for my example file:

```
{'created': [<Element created at 0x10b53a410>],  # notice, it's a list of matching children tags.
 'latitude': [],  # My example didn't contain these keys!
 'longitude': [],
 'mime': [],
 'timestamp': [],
 'title': [<Element title at 0x10b53a3c0>],
 'updated': [<Element updated at 0x10b53a460>]}
```

Instead of finding specific items, you can also iterate over all children tags of your note like this:

```
for note in root.xpath('//note'):  # Locate all tags under the root named 'note'. There's one.
    for child in note.getchildren():
        print child.tag, repr(child.text)
```

which outputs something like this:

```
title 'Untitled Note'
content '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>\n<!DOCTYPE en-note SYSTEM "http://xml.evernote.com/pub/enml2.dtd">\n<en-note style="word-wrap: break-word; -webkit-nbsp-mode: space; -webkit-line-break: after-white-space;">\nTest Entry\n<div>Another Entry</div>\n<div>Yet Another Entry<span style="-evernote-last-insertion-point:true;"/></div>\n</en-note>\n'
created '20131123T092930Z'
updated '20131123T092953Z'
note-attributes None
```

Hope that helps point you in the right direction!